# m2Eclipse plugin: What does 'Resolve Workspace Artifacts' do?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2eclipse, m2e

I'm sorry if I am asking a possibly-trivial question, but I am having so much trouble finding out exactly what *Resolve Workspace Artifacts* does in the Maven build window in the Eclipse IDE, using the M2Eclipse plugin. I'm referring to this:

[image: Picture of my maven run configuration screen]

Does anyone have any idea? I tried google-ing and stackoverflow-ing the solution; there are lots of bug requests/reports but no clear-cut descriptions of this option. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Assume you have two or more projects in your workspace e.g. `project1`, `project2` and so on. If `project1` is dependent on `project2` and `project3`, you just need to define the dependency of `project1` on `project2` and `project3`.

By enabling `Resolve Workspace Artifacts`, `m2Eclipse` will auto-build the `SNAPSHOT JAR` of `project2` and `project3` and add in the classpath of `project1`.

**In other words, it resolves the dependencies with workspace projects.**

Comment: it it does not work, it could be e.g. due to a dependency version mismatch similar to here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32308875/1915920

Comment: If I "close" a project in Eclipse, is it still being resolved?

Comment: @dokaspar, if you close the project then m2e will try to resolve it against to remote/local repositories.