# how to edit `.class` file in Maven dependency in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jar

Ok, so I have my Java projects, and under the Maven dependency project folder on the project explorer, I encounter a `jar` folder, and in it there is a `.class` file. Now, I clicked on `Download Sources` and I am able to view the `.class` file as a Java file, but I cannot edit it in Eclipse.

What should I do?

Comment: Why do you think you should be able to edit it?

Comment: @Cephalopod: since he stated here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15099790/how-to-edit-class-file-in-maven-dependency-in-eclipse#comment21243106_15099901 that the depended on project is his own (in the workspace)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot edit `.class` file(s). You can only edit `java` file(s) contained in the source code and recompile.

The sources that are downloaded by `maven` are a project SNAPSHOT generated by the `maven source plugin` for a given project at a given time, to aid in investigating the code, but certainly not to modify it.

These sources can be bound to the classpath and used for navigating the project source in an IDE, but they still remain read-only.

Comment: You can't edit .class files even if you have access to the source. You can only recompile the source.

Comment: @JeffStorey but you still can't edit .class files as java files? That is what I meant. Why the down vote?

Comment: I don't follow. You can't edit the class file (without modifying bytecode). If what you mean is that you can recompile the source then you should say that.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot edit jars and source jars directly.  You'd need to download the source code, and edit that.  You'd then have to go through the build process to re-build the jar, and install it as a new version in your maven repository.

Answer (score 0):

Class files are compiled binaries poised to be part of executable programs.

To modify them is an art in modifying compiled source code.  You probably don't want to do that.  If you want to generate a replacement, download the whole project and recompile it.

You may be obligated to do certain other things under such an action, by law you must abide by the licensing of the software, and recompiling and redistributing (which is what you'll be doing if you must recompile) often puts much heavier burdens on the developer than just "using" (depending on the licensing).

Comment: yea the software and project belongs to me, and I always rebuild the project in Eclipse.

Comment: If the dependent software and it's project belong to you, why are you in a question about recompiling it?  Change the upstream dependency (the upstream maven project) and re-release.  Odds are this is your project that has a dependency on something else, and substituting an ad-hoc something else in place of the original will violate all of Maven's ability to reproduce the results on a different machine.

Answer (score 0):

As has been previously mentioned, you can't modify .class files. You can download the source java files of the dependencies if available via:

```
mvn dependency:sources
mvn dependency:resolve -Dclassifier=javadoc
```

Answer (score 0):

(for confused readers: it's about Eclipse knowing via Maven config how to jump to the known/available (possibly own) project source file to edit it when it is actually linked in the code via some previously packaged jar (with `*.class` files in it))

*(We had the same problem, but it had worked before after some adjustments and we spend quite some time to figure this out ... )*

our (typical EAR archetype) dir structure:

```
[projx]
  |- [ejb]
       |- pom.xml
            ...
            <!-- A) PROBLEM: dependency resolution can't work in [web]/src/**/* -->
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

            <!-- B) OK: this is what we (and probably you) wanted -->
            <!-- <version>2.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version> -->
            ...
  |- [web]
       |- pom.xml
            ...
            <version>2.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            ...
            <dependency>
                <groupId>...</groupId>
                <artifactId>projx-ejb</artifactId>
                <type>ejb</type>

                <!-- C) a specific older version here would help it as well 
                        if you need it -->
                <!-- <version>1.0.3.Final</version> -->

                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            ...
  |- [ear]
       |- pom.xml
            ...
            <version>2.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            ...
  |- pom.xml

       <project ...>
        ...
        <version>2.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        ...
        <modules>
          <module>ejb</module>
          <module>web</module>
          <module>ear</module>
        </modules>
        ...
```

So the problem was that we **forgot to increase the `[ejb]/pom.xml//project/version` (A))**.
**After adjusting it similar to B)** (we actually reference a global `[projx]/pom.xml//project/properties/projx.version` property), it **worked again** like a charm.

(If we would have had depended explicitely on an older, e.g. `projx-ejb-1.0.3.Final.jar, JAR version, we could have gone for the C) approach where of course the workspace resolution again would not work, rightously.)

Comment: (if we would have looked more carefully at the opened class file (on CTRL+RIGHT-CLICK) we would have seen, that it was looking for a differently versioned jar `{user.home}/.m2/.../projx-ejb-1.0.3.Final.jar!/...` in our local maven repo) :-)