# Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin2.9:copy-dependencies (copy-dependencies) on project

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, maven, m2e

I'm pretty new to this(couple of months into maven), I came across this error while using Maven(apache-maven-3.2.3) in Eclipse(Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers-Juno Release) via m2e plugin(Eclipse.org-1.4.201x).

This struck me only when I had the following option "Resolve Workspace artifacts" selected in "Run Configuration" for Maven Build configuration instance.

For rest of the options there were no build issues and even command line maven commands worked without any hassle.

[image: Run Configuration Screenshot]

Error Log from Build Console: 
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.9:copy-dependencies (copy-dependencies) on project: Artifact has not been packaged yet. When used on reactor artifact, copy should be executed after packaging: see MDEP-187. -> [Help 1]

De-selecting/avoiding that option helped me resolve that issue but Can someone help me without more details around "Resolve Workspace artifacts"

Comment: this link explains what that option actually is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13205734/m2eclipse-plugin-what-does-resolve-workspace-artifacts-do