# IntelliJ - Resolve Maven Artifacts

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, intellij-idea

With IntelliJ IDEA, is it possible to "Resolve Workspace Artifacts"?

Meaning say I have a project

```
- root_folder
-->module1
---->pom.xml
-->module2
---->pom.xml
-->module3
---->pom.xml
-->project1
---->pom.xml
-->project2
---->pom.xml
-->project3
---->pom.xml
```

**This is an Eclipse project that I opened in IntelliJ** and with Eclipse when I run jetty:run on any of the 3 projects it can resolve the modules that is it dependent on because of the "Resolve Workspace Artifacts" of the Eclipse IDE, however for IntelliJ this is a bit of a challenge.

There is no parent POM, each module are quite stand-alone maven projects.

Using *IntelliJ* when I run `project1` which depends on `module1`; it is unable to resolve `module1` unless I `mvn install` the `module1` which is very cumbersome, I have to `mvn install` for every changes in the module. Not really productive at all.

Additionally, as mentioned the project is actually an forked Eclipse-based project that is why I cannot modify the maven structure to work-around the project, the only option I have is a solution at IDE level for the projects to be able to do something similar to *Resolve Workspace Artifacts*.

Similar to [m2Eclipse plugin: What does 'Resolve Workspace Artifacts' do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13205734/m2eclipse-plugin-what-does-resolve-workspace-artifacts-do)

Comment: Why would not have a parent POM?